# How is this equation called?

Tags: combinatorics, terminology, binomial-coefficients

I'm trying to figure out some math problems.

In particular I have this "In an office you have 6 clerks. How many ways can you select a team of 3 clerks?" and the solution given is: $$\binom{6}{3} = \frac{6!}{3!*3!} = 20.$$

I don't really understand how that works, so I'm trying to find some tutorial, but how exactly is this equation even called? I can't search for it, because I have no idea what I'm searching :)

Comment: It would help the site if you re-wrote the title of your question to something more specific and descriptive so that it would be helpful later on when someone is searching for something similar to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're referring to is called the "[binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Computing_the_value_of_binomial_coefficients)", spoken "$n$ choose $k$" for natural numbers $n, k$ with $k\le n$.

The equation you posted simply makes explicit how to compute the binomial coefficient of 
"$6$ choose $3$," which is denoted $\;\binom{6}{3}$. In this problem, $n = 6, k = 3$.

In general, to compute the number of ways to select $k$ items from $n$ items, without replacement, we compute:

$$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = \frac{n(n-1)...(n-k+1)}{k!}.$$

For your problem, we have that $\displaystyle \binom{6}{3} = \frac{6!}{3!(6-3)!} = \frac {6!}{3!3!} = \frac{6\cdot 5\cdot 4}{3\cdot2 \cdot 1} = \frac{120}{6} = 20.$

Answer (score 5):

It's the binomial coefficient, and you should google combination and permutation as a starter.